# Accessing nested key in JSON objects

Tags: python, json

I want to access a specific key value ("cote_1989_base") in Python to modify it. But I have a TypeError: string indices must be integers.

My code:

```py
import json

with open('demo_db_algolia_2019.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
    for x in data:
        cote1989base = x.get(["cote"][0]["cote_1989"]["cote_1989_eu"]["cote_1989_base"])
        print(cote1989base)
```

EDIT: Maybe I didn't explain this well because my entire JSON is in an array like this:

```
    [{
    "objectID": 10035,
    "cote":
    {
        "cote_1989":
        {
            "cote_1989_f": "750000F",
            "cote_1989_eu":
            {                    
                "cote_1989_base": 190140                    
            }
        },
        "cote_2004":
        {                
            "cote_2004_base": 173320                
        },
        "cote_2014":
        {                
            "cote_2014_base": 420800                
        },
        "cote_2017":
        {                
            "cote_2017_base": 939600                
        },
        "cote_2019":
        {                
            "cote_2019_base": 939600                
        }
    }
},
    {
    "objectID": 10202,
    "cote":
    {
        "cote_1989":
        {
            "cote_1989_f": "27000F",
            "cote_1989_eu":
            {                    
                "cote_1989_base": 6844                    
            }
        },
        "cote_2004":
        {
            "cote_2004_base": 10894                
        },
        "cote_2014":
        {
            "cote_2014_base": 23670
        },
        "cote_2017":
        {                
            "cote_2017_base": 46980
        },
        "cote_2019":
        {                
            "cote_2019_base": 51156
        }
    }
}
]
```

Does it change something to the main problem ?

Comment: What you have is not a valid json, also do `type(data)` to check the type of `data`

Comment: I edited the JSON. It's just a sample of my database but it is valid when I test it.

Comment: That code should raise `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` and that is exactly what it does here.

Comment: Well, `["cote"][0]` is a string so `["cote"][0]["cote_1989"]` just does not make sense. What else do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

you should access keys as following :

```
x.get("cote").get("cote_1989").get("cote_1989_eu").get("cote_1989_base")
```

or you can use the following function to simplify the code:

```
def find(data, key):
    parts = key.split('/')
    dd = data
    for part in parts:
         if ( dd == None or not isinstance(dd,dict)):
            return None
         dd = dd.get(part)         
    return dd
```

---

```
>>> data = { 'a' : { 'b' : { 'c' : { 'd':5} , 'c1':8 } }}
>>> find(data, 'a/b/c/d'))
5
>>> find(data, 'a/b/c2')
8
>>> find(data, 'z/b')
None
```

Comment: I have an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has not attribute 'get', maybe because sometimes, "cote_1989" keys have no value

Comment: probably. You can use the above function to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

This bit: `x.get(["cote"][0]["cote_1989"]` is certainly wrong. Here the square brackets are not a `dict` lookup, it is a list literal, so `["cote"][0]` evaluates to `"cote"`.

Then you proceed to subscript that with `["cote_1989"]` which is where your `TypeError` comes from.

You should chain `.get()` calls:

```
x.get("cote").get("cote_1989").get("cote_1989_eu").get("cote_1989_base")
```

That treats the `[0]` bit is 'line noise' in your original code, assuming your original JSON is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the `JSON`. There is a mismatch of braces. Use this.

```
import json


j = '''
{
    "objectID": 10035,
    "cote": {
        "cote_1989": {
            "cote_1989_f": "750000F",
            "cote_1989_eu": {
                "cote_1989_excp": 266196,
                "cote_1989_concours": 228168,
                "cote_1989_base": 190140,
                "cote_1989_be": 152112,
                "cote_1989_me": 114084,
                "cote_1989_ar": 76056,
                "cote_1989_epa": 38028
            }
        },
        "cote_2004": {
            "cote_2004_excp": 242648,
            "cote_2004_concours": 207984,
            "cote_2004_base": 173320,
            "cote_2004_be": 138656,
            "cote_2004_me": 103992,
            "cote_2004_ar": 69328,
            "cote_2004_epa": 34664
        }
    }
}'''

data = json.loads(j)
print(data['cote']['cote_1989']['cote_1989_eu']['cote_1989_base'])
```

Output:

```
190140
```

Comment: Change the line `data = json.loads(j)` to `data = json.loads(data_file.read())` and make sure the `JSON` doesn't have errors. If possible, use `vscode` to check the json file. Open the `.json` file using vscode, it'll show if the file has errors.